# It is possible to stack two different Add-Ons in Raspberry Pi 3?

Tags: pi-3, gps, modules, gsm

I need to create a project that has GPRS/GSM and GPS, but there are no products with both functionalities.
I found some Add-Ons that may work but I'm not sure if there is any way to stack both. I know that is impossible to put one on top of each other because there aren't compatible.
The products are:

- GPS -> https://www.itead.cc/raspberry-pi-gps-add-on-v2-0.html
- GSM/GPRS -> https://www.itead.cc/development-platform/raspi/add-on/raspberry-pi-sim900-gsm-gprs-add-on-v1-0.html OR https://www.itead.cc/raspberry-pi-sim800-gsm-gprs-add-on-v2-0.html

**There is any way to stack this Add-Ons in Raspberry Pi 3 Model B?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With these particular add-ons, no, because they both expect exclusive access to the serial port. You can get [GPIO stacking headers](https://elmwoodelectronics.ca/products/gpio-stacking-header-for-pi-a-b-pi-2-extra-long-2x20-pins) for adding multiple HATs, but you always have to check if there's pin contention. [pinout.xyz](https://pinout.xyz) is a good resource.

Boards based on other chipsets such as the SIM908 combine GSM/GPRS and GPS on  one module.

Comment: Thanks! I searched for that product (SIM908) but I can't find the complete board. I only find the chip... I'm a newbie on what regards to electronic projects so if I find the complete board it will be perfect.