# Using GPIO on the Bitwizard DMX hat board

Tags: gpio, sensor, pi-4, hat

I have a rpi 4, with a relays board on top of it, and a Bitwizard DMX hat board on top of that.
The Bitwzard board doesn't have a male header on the top, so I am unable to connect my sensors. It was shipped with a 2x13 stackable header, which I don't know what to do with.

The Bitwizard board is this one : https://bitwizard.nl/shop/DMX-interface-for-Raspberry-pi

The 2x13 stackable header looks like this one : https://www.robotshop.com/ca/en/2x23-pin-stackable-header.html

So the question is, how can I stack everything, so I can connect my sensor on top of the DMX board?

Comment: This might help: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/104705/how-to-tap-tee-fork-the-rpi-gpio-pins-covered-blocked-by-a-hat-phat-bo

Comment: There is some great ideas in this post and thoses linked as well. Thank you!

Comment: Hi @M.Parent, your are welcome. Cheers.