# Stacking up multiple grove base HATs on Raspberry Pi

Tags: hardware, i2c, hat

I want to stack multiple Grove base HATs on a single Raspberry Pi.
This is the HAT i am using
https://wiki.seeedstudio.com/Grove_Base_Hat_for_Raspberry_Pi

My application needs to interface 24 analog sensors and 9 I2C based sensors on the same Pi. So I need to stack more Grove base HATs for the above scenario.

Is it possible to do that?

Comment: This might help: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/104705/how-to-tap-tee-fork-the-rpi-gpio-pins-covered-blocked-by-a-hat-phat-bo

Comment: @tlfong thanks for your suggestion, but my grove base HAT is based on I2C. if we stack multiple HATs on the same I2C pin of the Pi problem may occur?. I am i wrong or not plz clarify.

Comment: Well, it is a bad idea, especially during prototyping, to stack too many HATs at the same time. One workaround is to make good use of 40 pin GPIO extension cables for troubleshooting and development. Loading more than 8 devices on the same I2C bus is also problematic..